# Delete the Merged column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

[image]

I want to delete The first column and select the close price i.e https://www.CryptoDataDownload.com

Here is the csv https://www.cryptodatadownload.com/cdd/Binance_AAVEUSDT_d.csv

I have tried

```
df.drop('https://www.CryptoDataDownload.com,axis=1)
```

But got this
[image: It have 0 columns]

Or  How I can select the **close price Column**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is the question you are asking because you mention a merged column. In general, to select a `close` column you do `df['close']`. To drop a `unix` column `df.drop('unix',axis=1)`.

UPDATE:
The actual problem was that the csv file header was in the second row, with some garbage at the first row.
When reading this csv file the location of header need to be specified explicitly, like that  `pd.read_csv('Binance_AAVEUSDT_d.csv',header=1)`.

After that columns name are correct and all works as expected

Comment: I tried df['close'] But see 'close' is not a colunm SeeIt have 149 rows × 0 columns

Comment: Ok, your actual problem was that the csv file's header is located at second row, i/o first. That's why you get `https://www.CryptoDataDownload.com` as a column name. You need to specify that when you read the csv file. Like that   `pd.read_csv('Binance_AAVEUSDT_d.csv',header=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Binance_AAVEUSDT_d.csv')
data = data.reset_index()
ndata = data.iloc[1:]
ndata.columns = data.iloc[0]
ndata['close']
```

Output:

```
1      100.30000000
2       99.30000000
3       94.10000000
4       91.30000000
5       90.20000000
           ...     
582          32.135
583          36.075
584          40.795
585          41.393
586          39.390
Name: close, Length: 586, dtype: object
```

Comment: Or you can just do `pd.read_csv('Binance_AAVEUSDT_d.csv',header=1)`